# php array returning same values in loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to loop through each key but i am facing a problem of same value repeating inside for each loop

> **Here is example of my current code and result ([click here](https://3v4l.org/CDFpE))**

here is my code so far

```
<?php
$data2 = array(
        'category_name' => '33287*100*prescription*1,32457*1250*lab*1'
    );
    $result = array('0' => (object)$data2);

    foreach ($result as $key => $category) {
        $category_name = explode(',', $category->category_name);
    }

    $newresults=[];
    foreach ($category_name as $key) {
        $category->category_name = $key;
        $newresults[]=$category;
    }

    $result=$newresults;

    $newresults=[];

        $category->items_count = 0;
        
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {

            list($sale_key, $sale_value) = explode('*', $value->category_name);
            // $category->items_count += count($sale_value);
            $newresults[]=$category;
        }

    $result=$newresults;
```

i am expect the result should be

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 33287*100*prescription*1
            [items_count] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 32457*1250*lab*1
            [items_count] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: **added please check the code**

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that you're relying only on the last version of `$category` after you've finished looping it earlier - you'd have to be using it within the loop where it's assigned, in order to get each value in turn, or you could use `$value` from your last foreach loop.

But as a general observation, this code has way too many loops etc. just for processing one array in the way you've requested. Here's a much simpler version:

```
$category_name = '33287*100*prescription*1,32457*1250*lab*1';
$category_name_arr = explode(',', $category_name);

print_r($category_name_arr);

$newresults=[];

foreach ($category_name_arr as $cat) {
    $newresults[] = (object) array("category_name" => $cat, "items_count" => 0);
}

print_r($newresults);
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/065a32b40f67e00aa85f0f5b58ecacd510f2f38a

---

If you still need to be able to support multiple lines of input, you can do it like this, by just merging the exploded arrays before you process them:

```
$data = array(
    '33287*100*prescription*1,32457*1250*lab*1',
    '33222*900*prescription*3,22233*1200*lab*2',
    );
$category_name_arr = [];

foreach ($data as $category_name)
{
  $category_name_arr = array_merge($category_name_arr, explode(',', $category_name));
}

print_r($category_name_arr);

$newresults=[];

foreach ($category_name_arr as $cat) {
    $newresults[] = (object) array("category_name" => $cat, "items_count" => 0);
}

print_r($newresults);
```

Comment: this is criteria to keep all kind of loops can you please help me to fix the problem in current code i have this is not to just print this is logical pieces of code i don't care about performance

Comment: The performance difference isn't going to be noticeable. I was thinking of the readability and maintainability of your code actually. Why do you "need" to keep all the loops? That doesn't make any sense, when you can write it much more easily like this. The other loops weren't necessary or helpful, they just made it harder to work out what the code was going to do. Also, assigning $newresults, then emptying it and reassigning it all over again was another redundant step

Comment: Anyway my first sentence in the answer explains how to fix the current code, if you so wish.

Comment: i am agreeing with you and learning, i need to keep on the same code because i need to keep adding new things in future

Comment: i am newbie here and can't understand your sentence very well, can you please edit your answer with my code

Comment: What new things, exactly? Be specific, if you have a definite requirement. There's nothing you need to add to those loops which could not be done with the single loop in my answer, as far as I can see.

Comment: (I guess you _could_ reinstate the $data2 array and accompanying loop if you needed more lists if input data, but that would be fairly easy. It's the last loop which was the completely pointless one, and caused most of the redundancy.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241347/discussion-between-uzthegeek-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

adding $category = new stdClass();

```
foreach ($category_name as $key) {
```

> $category = new stdClass();

```
            $category->category_name = $key;
            $newresults[]=$category;
        }
```