# php array returning duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to loop through each key but i am facing a problem of same value repeating inside for each loop

> Please be noted we should keep on same code structure multiple foreach it's requirement i already posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70831072/php-array-returning-same-values-in-loop) but didn't get solution instead of solution entire new code as answer imposed on me and nobody is actually taking care of it

> **Here is example of my current code and result ([click here](https://3v4l.org/CDFpE))**

here is my code so far

```
<?php
    $data2 = array(
        'category_name' => '33287*100*prescription*1,32457*1250*lab*1'
    );
    $result = array('0' => (object)$data2);

    foreach ($result as $key => $category) {
        $category_name = explode(',', $category->category_name);
    }

    $newresults=[];
    foreach ($category_name as $key) {
        $category->category_name = $key;
        $newresults[]=$category;
    }    
    $result=$newresults;

    $newresults=[];
    $category->items_count = 0;
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        list($sale_key, $sale_value) = explode('*', $value->category_name);
        // $category->items_count += count($sale_value);
        $newresults[]=$category;
    }
    $result=$newresults;
```

i am getting the wrong results like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 33287*100*prescription*1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 33287*100*prescription*1
        )

)
```

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: i am looking to get result like this Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 33287*100*prescription*1
            [items_count] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category_name] => 32457*1250*lab*1
            [items_count] => 0
        )

)

Comment: @uzthegeek first of all use self explanatory variable names. It will definitely simplify the debugging. You make a ``$result`` then build ``$newresults`` and overwrite the original ``$result`` then clear the ``$newresults`` to build new set of data and assign it back to ``$result`` meanwhile playing with ``$category``. This messing up with variable names make the code difficult for reading.

Comment: As ADyson said in your other question, you cannot use `$category` outside of the loop (unless you full understand the consequences).

Comment: Including what you commented out, it seems like this is roughly what you are looking for: https://3v4l.org/7nkgb

Comment: @ chris you're real hero after adding $category = new stdClass(); in 2nd foreach and adding & in foreach ($result as $key => &$value) fix the problem can you please tell me what both changes did and why we need to put them cheer :)

Comment: @ChrisHaas go ahead to answer so i can accept it

Comment: @ChrisHaas some data removed from array when adding $category = new stdClass(); a little problem to be solved

Comment: What data is removed?

Comment: @ChrisHaas after follow your instructions here is full code so far , https://3v4l.org/BeVD1 when i print_r($result) $category->patient and $category->ref removed as you can see in $reporting_data i already have them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241357/discussion-between-uzthegeek-and-chris-haas).

Comment: I don't chat. You gave us a subset of code, which is generally good, however you went too far. Using this expanded source array, we have no idea how it should look as an output. The code I posted appears to work 100% with what you did give us. Please update this post with your closer-to-actual source data, redacted as necessary, but we need to know the general shape. Any business-logic stuff can be omitted, for instance where you get things from another data source. Also include what the output should look like.

Comment: @ChrisHaas stackoverflow not allow me to edit my question, would you please check this example data -> https://3v4l.org/EdMgj#v7.0.0

Comment: @ChrisHaas or try this example -> https://3v4l.org/NC2RY#v7.0.0

Comment: @ChrisHaas my goal is explode $category->category_name 2 time(s) with , and * than loop each *explode but render all actual data again inside *explode input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, because you are reusing variable names, and also using them when their scope might not be correct or accepted, you are causing some confusion.

The code below brings the bottom loop *inside* of the top loop, because that's where the context really lives. Creating a temporary loop only adds to the potential confusion. If that doesn't work with the additional logic, more changes will be needed. I also changed a bunch of the variable names to hopefully make things more obvious. See the comments in the code for more details.

```php
$reporting_data = array(
    'category_name' => '33287*100*prescription*1,32457*1250*lab*1,32459*1500*lab*1,32460*400*lab*1,32461*600*lab*1,32468*950*lab*1,32470*950*lab*1,33291*2500*lab*1,33292*2500*lab*1,47516*2000*lab*1,49209*0*lab*1,56835*2400*lab*1,56836*2400*lab*1',
    'patient' => '28370',
    'date' => 1643030497,
    'ref' => '371',
);

// Create array of objects
$reporting_data_as_objects[] = (object)$reporting_data;

$results = [];
foreach ($reporting_data_as_objects as &$obj) {

    // Setup base data that is shared across all items
    $obj->reception_data_sum = 0;
    $obj->references_data_sum = 0;
    $obj->actual_price = 0;

    $category_names = explode(',', $obj->category_name);

    // Loop over the comma-delimited parts of category_name
    foreach ($category_names as $category_name) {

        // Clone our template object
        $tmp = clone $obj;

        // The second item of the asterisk-delimted field is the price
        // We used $_ to indicate that we aren't interested in the first item.
        list($_, $sale_value) = explode('*', $category_name);

        // Set object-specific fields on our clone
        $tmp->category_name = $category_name;
        $tmp->actual_price = (int)$sale_value;

        // Add the clone to the array
        $results[] = $tmp;
    }
}

// Always unset by-ref variables of a foreach
unset($obj);

print_r($results);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/95KAQ

Comment: hass it's working thanks

Comment: hass i am still getting an error the $sale_key cannot be sacrificed with $_ because i am calling model function s with $sale_key i should keep on same structure

Comment: Okay, you can just use it like you had. This was just a sample.